# create event on selected google calendar on same account

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have a Google account and there are three Google Calendars in my calendar list.  I am trying to create an event with selected Google Calendar. I am using php.

```
here is list of google calendars.
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| calName              | calid                                         |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| harish@gmail.com     | harish@gmail.com                          |
| Contacts             | #contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com         |
| Holidays in India    | en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

harish@gmail.com is a "`primary`" calendar. When I create an event in this calendar, the event created successfully using PHP.

However when I try to create an event in "`Contacts, Holidays in India`" calendars, it never creates event using PHP for these calendars.

My code:

```
            $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => $eventname,
            'location' => $address,
            'description' => $description,
            'start' => array(
              'dateTime' => $s,
              'timeZone' => $timezone,
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => $e,
              'timeZone' => $timezone,
            ),
            'attendees' => array(
              array('email' => $contactemail),
            ),
            'reminders' => array(
              'useDefault' => FALSE,
              'overrides' => array(
                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
              ),
            ),
          ));

 $calid = 'en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'; // this is static for now

        $event = $service->events->insert($calid, $event);
```

Error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with    message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.indian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events: (403) Forbidden' in /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google  /Http/REST.php:110
>      Stack trace:
>      #0 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
>       #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #2 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>       #3 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
>       #4 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
>       #5 /var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Ser in **/var/www/myinvitebig.com/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php** on line **110**

Answer (score 1):

> 'en.indian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'

Is one of the many Holiday calendars that were rolled out to Google calendar in [2014](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2014/02/new-holiday-calendars.html).  These are public calendars within Google calendar anyone can subscribe to them.  However just because you have subscribed to said calendar doesn't mean that you have write access to it.    In the case of the holiday calendars you have read only access.

> (403) Forbidden

Means that you do not have permissions to do what ever it is you are trying to do.   IN this case adding an event to a calendar you do not personally have permissions to write to.